# Stored Procedure doesn't like utf-16

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

All,

I have a stored procedure on SQL Server 2005 that accepts an XML argument.
When I execute:

```
exec PutResultsOnDb '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><loads of Xml data>'
```

I get the error: 
`XML parsing: line 1, character 39, unable to switch the encoding`

However when I do

```
exec PutResultsOnDb '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><loads of Xml data>'
```

It works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805259/storing-utf-16-unicode-data-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case fails because you're declaring that you have UTF-16 encoding XML in an ASCII string. The second case most likely works because you don't have any characters above 127 and so UTF-8 is indistinguishable from ASCII.

If you want to declare the XML as UTF-16, you need to declare the string as UCS-2 (which is [mostly compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2)) by using an `N` prefix, e.g. the following should work:

```
exec PutResultsOnDb N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><loads of Xml data>'
```