# How to send super-script & sub-script numbers from C# to SQL server DB

Tags: c#, sql, subscript, seeding, superscript

I have dot-net core, C# at server side. I want to seed some chemical equations as data, which contains both super-script & sub-script. I tried UTF-16 code **("\U00B2")** for **super-script 2** in C# string, but it stopped showing all options in dropdown menu in UI (Angular).
What should I do so that I can keep super-script & sub-script in chemical formulas, so that when it gets seeded, it shows up as it is in dropdown menu in UI?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How is column defined in database?  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805259/storing-utf-16-unicode-data-in-sql-server?force_isolation=true